# Local notification sound should be on by default

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I am developing an iphone app in which i am using `UILocalNotifications`. When notification occurs, notification banner is displaying but there is no sound. i.e sound in disabled(off) from `NotificationCenter`. How can i enable(On) notification sound by default without going to settings. Thanks is advance

I am using

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification setAlertBody:alertBody];
[notification setFireDate:thedate2];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Comment: Go to settings-notifications-<<your app>> then check sound is enabled for that. If not enable it

Comment: i think it's not possible without going to settings..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely not possible to override the global Notification Center settings programatically.

If it were, it would lead to chaos where apps ignore peoples preferences.

Imagine you're in an interview or meeting and some stupid app makes a ridiculous noise - even though you had your notifications on silent, how annoying would that be?

Comment: I also think like that but some apps like skype etc have already sound on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    UILocalNotification *localNotification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification1.fireDate = thedate2;
    localNotification1.alertBody = alertBody;
    localNotification1.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
    localNotification1.soundName = @"sound.caf";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification1];
```

Use a sound with `.caf` format. I think this will help you. :)